# How to extend values to next non-null in pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `Series` like so:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0])
>>> s[s==0] = pd.np.nan
>>> s
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    5.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
dtype: float64
```

and I'd like to 'extend' the values, as illustrated here:

```
>>> t = s.shift()
>>> for _ in range(100000):
...     s[s.isnull()] = t
...     if not s.isnull().any():
...             break
...     t = t.shift()
...
>>> s
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
6    5.0
7    5.0
8    5.0
dtype: float64
```

But I'd like something more vectorized and efficient. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `fillna`:

```
>>> s.fillna(method='ffill')
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
6    5.0
7    5.0
8    5.0
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy forward filling based on [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
def numpy_ffill(s):
    arr = s.values
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(len(mask)),0)
    out = arr[np.maximum.accumulate(idx)]
    return pd.Series(out)
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: s
Out[41]: 
0    1.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    5.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
dtype: float64

In [42]: numpy_ffill(s)
Out[42]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
6    5.0
7    5.0
8    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank god that pandas sometimes gives us a level of abstraction :)

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, it seems like for series, pandas method is doing quite well in terms of performance.